# How to Clone/Copy a POCO Entity for MongoDB with BsonSerializer in the C# Driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

What's the best way to make a new copy of a MongoDB POCO entity using the official C# driver?

I've tried this;

```
    public T Clone()
    {
        var bsonWriter = new BsonDocumentWriter(new BsonDocument(), BsonDocumentWriterSettings.Defaults);
        BsonSerializer.Serialize(bsonWriter, this);
        var newDoc = bsonWriter.ToBsonDocument(typeof(T));
        var e = BsonSerializer.Deserialize(newDoc , typeof(T));
        return e as T;

    }//Clone()
```

But all I get is an empty object full of nulls. The POCO object does NOT inherit from BsonDocument by the way, but it does serialize fine and I want to capitalise on all the Bson Attributes it's decorated with, which is why I don't want to copy it some other way. I want a copy as the DB Driver would do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's much easier than that.

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;

//...

var test = new Test { Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(), Name = "Jack" };
var doc = test.ToBsonDocument();
var copy = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Test>(doc);
```

You can look in the ToBsonDocument extension method if you'd like to see how it works.

Comment: doesn't work for arrays